# Dagger constantly refuses to inject dependency

Tags: android, dagger

Unfortunately I fail to use even the simplest Dagger examples. Let's take a look at my code (I got rid most of UI and auto-generated code as it was not relevant):

- My Activity

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
      @Inject
      RoomDAO roomDAO;
      private ObjectGraph objectGraph;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(RoomModule.class);
          roomDAO = objectGraph.get(RoomDAO.class);
          roomDAO.hai();
     }

  }
  ```
- RoomDAO & RoomDAOImpl

  ```
  public interface RoomDAO {
       String hai();
  }

  public class RoomDAOImpl implements RoomDAO {
      private DBHelper dbHelper;

     @Inject
     public RoomDAOImpl(){
       //I tried even this constructor in case dbHelper was the guy causing problems,
       //but it wasn't!
     }


     public RoomDAOImpl(DBHelper dbHelper){
        this.dbHelper = dbHelper;
     }
     @Override
     public String hai() {
        return "oh hai";
     }
  }
  ```
- RoomModule

  ```
  @Module(
      injects = {MainActivity.class},
      library = true
  )
  public class RoomModule {
       @Provides @Singleton
       public RoomDAO provideRoomDao(){
           return new RoomDAOImpl();
       }
  }
  ```

`DBHelper` doesn't have anything interesting (just some little database stuff, onCreate, onUpdate, nothing more really).
I thought that line `roomDAO = objectGraph.get(RoomDAO.class);` would make Dagger to (more or less) call `RoomModule#provideRoomDao()` and make me a nice, brand new RoomDAOImpl object (or take it from the sky if it is already created). However, my graph does not have `RoomDAO` in `injectableTypes`, so my app is failing at line `roomDAO = objectGraph.get(RoomDAO.class);` when calling `ObjectGraph#getInjectableTypeBinding` (because `moduleClass == null`). What am I missing?

**EDIT.**
OK, probably this is the time to show how DBHelper looks like.

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // (...) not relevant config stuff i.e. DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_VERSION

    @Inject
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
         super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
         //(...) creating tables
     }

    @Override
       public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
         //(...) updating tables
     }
}
```

```
@Module(
    injects = {MainActivity.class}
)
public class RoomModule {
     @Provides @Singleton
     public RoomDAO provideRoomDao(DBHelper dbHelper){
         return new RoomDAOImpl(dbHelper);
     }

     @Provides
     public Context getAppContext(){
           return MainActivity.getAppContext();
     }
 }
```

I decided to use second approach you suggested, as it seems to be more Spring-like and I am more familiar with that. 
`MainActivity.getAppContext();` is a static method that returns the value of static field Context. It's a little embarrassing, but I'm pretty ignorant if it comes to Context as I have never seen the real usage of it (I was always putting `this` where I needed Context).
That's where comes the question - does `RoomModule#getAppContext()` seem to be a probable source of bugs? `DBHelper` probably will be fine, because it is a singleton and once created it should be theoretically available everywhere. Is adding some qualifier to this guy `@Provides public Context getAppContext()` going to make this solution more or less free of bugs? Or maybe there is a better way to provide a Context for `DBHelper` constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remove the `library = true` line. Do not just add `library = true` or `complete = false`, especially in basic examples. These lines surpress helpful warnings.

When running the application, you will get an `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No inject registered for tmp.RoomDAO. You must explicitly add it to the 'injects' option in one of your modules.
```

---

There are two ways to retrieve instances from the `ObjectGraph`, using `get(...)`, or using `inject(...)`.

- When using `get(...)`, you will need to add the class you try to get to the `injects` option in your module (like the exception tells you to):

  ```
  @Module(injects = {MainActivity.class, RoomDAO.class})
  ```

  This will make your application work. You actually don't need the `@Inject` annotation on your `RoomDAO` field.
- Another way is to use `inject`, with wich you *do* need the `@Inject` annotation. `inject` looks at the annotated fields of the class, and uses the `ObjectGraph` to assign values to them. Using this method, you don't need to add `RoomDAO` to the `injects` option of your module:

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(RoomModule.class);
      objectGraph.inject(this);
      roomDAO.hai();
  }
  ```

---

Finally, your `RoomDAOImpl` depends on `DBHelper`. For completeness, you can do that like this:

DBHelper:

```
public class DBHelper {
    @Inject
    public DBHelper() {
    }
}
```

RoomModule:

```
@Module(
        injects = {MainActivity.class}
)
public class RoomModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public RoomDAO provideRoomDao(DBHelper dbHelper) {
        return new RoomDAOImpl(dbHelper);
    }
}
```

RoomDAOImpl:

```
public class RoomDAOImpl implements RoomDAO {

    private final DBHelper mDBHelper;

    public RoomDAOImpl(final DBHelper dbHelper) {
        mDBHelper = dbHelper;
    }

    @Override
    public String hai() {
        return "oh hai";
    }
}
```

The `DBHelper` instances in `provideRoomDao` is created for you by Dagger. To do that, Dagger needs an `@Inject` annotation on the constructor of `DBHelper`. Since you instantiate `RoomDAOImpl` yourself, you don't need to add the `@Inject` annotation to the constructor of `RoomDAOImpl`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time and answer which worked. I decided to use the second approach you suggested. Anyway, you kinda predicted what I would be doing next and here comes non-mock version of RoomDAO constructor. I edited my question, as DBHelper has not that trivial constructor - as it uses Context. Could you take a look at my question once again and try to assess if I commited a crime or not? ;)

Comment: Yes that's the right mindset. A better way of providing the Context is to pass it to the constructor of your RoomModule, and keep it as a field. Then you don't need the static call to getAppContext.

Comment: Note that you did the right thing to return the application Context, and not just the Activity instance. Passing around the Activity Context is dangerous and a well known source of memory leaks.